# Process of animating paths using Quart2D

Tags: ios, objective-c, quartz-2d

I am new to using Quartz2D, and to start small I wanted to draw a line, but have that line be animated from start to finish. From the blogs I have read and similar questions I have looked at, it seems I need to set a path for layer, and animate on that layer. The problem for me is, even though a layer has a path property, I am unsure how to go about properly settings up a path for it.

I have a UIView displaying, and it shows a line just fine if I comment out the animation code.

```
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

CGFloat components[] = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0};

CGColorRef color = CGColorCreate(colorspace, components);

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color);

CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 0, 0);
CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, 300, 400);

CGContextStrokePath(context);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
CGColorRelease(color);

CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
pathAnimation.duration = 10.0;
pathAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
pathAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
//[aLayer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"strokeEndAnimation"];
```

What do I need to do to animate a line from start to finish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I've used to animate a line being drawn, make sure to import Quartz of course:

```
//Create the bezier path that will hold all the points of data
UIBezierPath* bezierPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[[UIColor greenColor] setFill];
[bezierPath fill];
[[UIColor redColor] setStroke];
[bezierPath stroke];

for (int i = 10 ; i < 20; i++) {
    //If its the first point we need to make sure and move to that point not add to it
    if (i == 10)
        [bezierPath moveToPoint: CGPointMake(10, 10)];
    else
        [bezierPath addLineToPoint: CGPointMake(i * 2, i * 3)];
}


CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
shapeLayer.fillColor = nil;
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 10.0f;
shapeLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound;
shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.CGPath;

CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
pathAnimation.duration = 10.0;
pathAnimation.fromValue = @(0.0f);
pathAnimation.toValue = @(1.0f);

[shapeLayer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"strokeEnd"];

[self.view.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
```

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I needed. Couldn't find any tuts giving a full solution such as this, just had the animation part. Thanks